# delete first page from PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is there a way we can delete the first page of the PDF using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no direct way to remove pages from a PDF using iTextSharp.

However, you can copy all the pages you want from a PDF and skip the pages you don't want.  In your case you'd copy out all but the first page.

I wrote a method that does this based on the code I found on [this blog entry](http://jamesewelch.com/2008/11/14/how-to-extract-pages-from-a-pdf-document/).

Comment: If you vote someone's answer as the best, please, be courteous and at give him/her a point for that.

Comment: @jay-riggs  the blog entry is gone :(

Answer (score 2):

PdfReader reader_SecondPdf = new PdfReader(pdf_of_Second_File);

```
        for (j = 2; j <= reader_SecondPdf.NumberOfPages; j++)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

using itext 7 (thanks to @mkl)

```
    public static void ExtractPagesFromPdf(string inputFile, string outputFile, int start, int end)
    {
        PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(inputFile);
        PdfDocument docIn = new PdfDocument(inputPdf);

        PdfWriter outputWriter = new PdfWriter(outputFile);
        PdfDocument docOut = new PdfDocument(outputWriter);

        // retrieve the total number of pages
        int pageCount = docIn.GetNumberOfPages();

        if (end < start || end > pageCount)
        {
            end = pageCount;
        }

        var merge = new PdfMerger(docOut);

        merge.Merge(docIn, start, end);

        merge.Close();
    }
```

from archive.org snapshot using itextsharp 5.x
http://web.archive.org/web/20110619070947/http://www.jamesewelch.com:80/2008/11/14/how-to-extract-pages-from-a-pdf-document/

Comment: Hhmmm, at least in current iText versions there are better ways to do this; probably not at the time of @JayR's answer, though...