# Rotate pages 180 degrees

Tags: pdf, itext

Has anyone had trouble with iTextSharp when deleting a page when copying all pages from a source to destination PDF file? We seem to see the destination rotated 180 degrees with some PDF file versions. Most are just fine. Haven't pinned it down exactly. We are just beginning testing the scenario.

[delete first page from PDF using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907354/delete-first-page-from-pdf-using-itextsharp)

or

http://www.jamesewelch.com/2008/11/14/how-to-extract-pages-from-a-pdf-document/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're having trouble with rotated pages.  Check `PdfReader.getPageRotation(pageNum)`.

I've actually never encountered a page that was rotated 180 degrees.  I suspect that between iText's normal behavior and your code, you're take a +90 degree page and turning it into a -90 page, or visa versa.

Without more detail/source/sample-PDFs its impossible to tell exactly what's going wrong.